# Replacing multiple character using awk with , comma for csv

Tags: awk

Dears,

I have the following list which some time contain 10000 entries:

```
listID.14.1 = STRING: test1
listID.14.2 = STRING: test2
listID.14.3 = STRING: test3
listID.14.4 = STRING: test4
listID.14.5 = STRING: test5 
listID.14.6 = STRING: test6
listID.14.7 = STRING: test7
```

I want the output to be like this

```
test1,test2,test3,...,test7
```

I used the following code which will be more accurate better than new line cause some list contain new line

```
awk -F "listID.${listID}.([0-9]+|[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{1,5}) = STRING: " '{print ","$2}'
```

but the output happened to be:

```
,test1
,test2
,test3
,test4
```

which is wrong not like this "test1,test2,test3, ...., testn" as I want I'm not sure how to modify my code to result as I shown above, Some idea I'm thinking of adding new line at the beginning but the code it didn't work for me I think I used wrong format. Need some help

```
awk -F "\nlistID.${listID}.([0-9]+|[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{1,5}) = STRING: " '{print ","$2}'
```

Need some help
Also second question about this code:

```
awk -F "listID.${listID}.([0-9]+|[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{1,5}) = STRING: " '{print ","$2}'
```

does this specific format ([0-9]+|[0-9]{3}|[0-9]{1,5}) check for number between 1 to 10000

Comment: you could follow up with `sed s/\n//g` on awk's result !?

Comment: `awk '{printf("%s%s", (cnt++)?",":"", $NF)}END{print ""}' file` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the text after last space and print it separated with a comma:

```
 cut -d' ' -f4 | paste -sd,
```

Tested with:

```
cat <<EOF |
listID.14.1 = STRING: test1
listID.14.2 = STRING: test2
listID.14.3 = STRING: test3
listID.14.4 = STRING: test4
listID.14.5 = STRING: test5 
listID.14.6 = STRING: test6
listID.14.7 = STRING: test7 
EOF
cut -d' ' -f4 | paste -sd,
```

outputs:

```
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
awk '{printf "%s,",$NF} END {print ""}' file
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7,
```

If you do not like the extra comma at the end:

```
awk '{printf (NR==1?"":",")"%s",$NF} END {print ""}' file
test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
awk '{ a = a","$4 } END {print a }' < foo
```

Where foo is the file containing your data, this will left a leading comma

```
,test1,test2,test3,test4,test5,test6,test7
```

You can remove it with sed `| sed 's/^,//'`.

Answer (score 0):

If `Perl` is your option, please try:

```
perl -lane 'push(@ary, pop(@F)); END {print join(",", @ary)};' list.txt
```

- `-l` option automatically removes a record separator of input lines and add
  it back to the output lines.
- `-a` option enables the auto-splitting mode on blank characters as `AWK` does
  and assigns the fields to array `@F`.
- `pop(@F)` returns the last element of `@F` to add to `@ary`.
- `-n` option makes `perl` iterate over input records as `AWK` does.

BTW answering your 2nd question, the regex `/^([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|10000)$/` will match the numbers from 1 to 10000.

So your last line will be someting like:

```
awk -F "listID\.${listID}\.([1-9][0-9]{0,3}|10000) = STRING: " '{printf ",%s", $2}'
```

although setting `FS` to the complex string as above may not be a good idea. It will not work as you expect because it does not skip the lines which do not match the regex.

Hope this helps.